Recursion with odd options
Consider a function $f(n)$ defined from $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(n+1)= f(n) + \frac{1}{f(n)^2}$. Given that $f(1)=1$, which of the following options are correct?

$f(9000)>30$
$f(1000)<10$
$f(n)≤ 2024$ always
$f(n)$ may be greater than $10000$

I have very little or no progress. I tried $f(n+1)- f(n) = \frac{1}{f(n)^2}$.
Kept on putting values of n and adding all equations but unable to reach any conclusion. Please help.
There may be more than one options correct.

Does this answer your question? Proving $a_{9000}>30$ when $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+ \frac{1} {a_n^2}$

A partial answer:
The sequence is strictly increasing and, if you assume that it has a limit $\ell$, from the equality $\ell = \ell + \frac{1}{\ell^2}$, you realize that the limit is actually $+\infty$. So, (C) is false and (D) is true.
The links provided by @MartinR answer (A) and (B). Showing that $f(n) > \sqrt[3]{3n}$ confirms that (A) is true and (B) is false.

$f(n) > \sqrt[3]{3n}$ also shows that (C) is false and (D) is true, so it answers all questions – that's why I voted to close the question as a duplicate.

@MartinR You are correct, I just posted this solution for (C) and (D) because it does not depend on deriving any bounds for $f(n)$.
